# CSS / JS: How by default (!) scroll a block element with overflow-x set to auto horizontally to the far right?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an element that shows my GitHub contributions, this file has static width and to make it look nice on smaller devices I decided to use `overflow-x` set to `auto` to allow horizontal swipe with finger gesture.

I would like to see the scroll position to the very right by default so that the most recent contributions are being shown.

I assume it's not possible with CSS and I need to use some JS?

Here's the basic CSS that I wrote:

```
.my-github-contributions-chart-wrapper {
    @include breakpoint(medium down) {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

Here is what I want to achieve. Currently I have to manually scroll to the right.

[image]

Comment: Just curious if you need to have the newest on the right and not the left. I don't have the code but you may be able to use CSS `direction` and just put the newest stuff on the left where the scroll defaults to.

Comment: Hi @Justin, but I call GitHub and fetch whatever it generates on its end. https://mattkomarnicki.com/github/contributions take a look at the source.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure how it could be done without JS and using something like `scrollTo()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that I can do this in pure CSS. I forgot about `rtl` direction.

```
@include breakpoint(medium down) {
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: visible;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Simply apply `direction: rtl;` to the element with the `overflow-x` defined.